# postgres shared connection issue

Tags: c, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.0 database , where In my C program I connect the database only once
and using fork I generate processes , where all my child program shares the connection 
Most of the time it works correctly , 
In some cases child A gets the query error of child B , and It also gets the query time out issues and all

My question is , Is there any wrong to share the connections ?
per second it may create 1 to 5 processes at the max

Note: 
I never closes the connection at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea for threads to share a single database connection because you'll run into the exact issue that you described in your question: one thread can get the output of another thread's request.  Instead, you'll want each thread to connect separately.  If you have a lot of threads, you might want to consider making a [connection pool](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling).

Comment: Thanks , but FYI I used fork , is your answer applicable for both fork and thread ? , kindly reply

Comment: Yes.  If two processes (either started by threads or via `fork`) share the same database connection, then the database has no way of telling which process made a request or to which process it should send output.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-connect.html (as a case of "don't do that")